# Overlaying a PNG on top of a background colour. Goal - create transitions between sections

Tags: html, css

Reference image - from oneolympus.com:

[image]

If you refer to the image above (which was created through a page-builder), that entire component is actually a section, (1) with a background gradient, and (2) those white waves are a png that is overlayed on top of the background (positioned at the bottom of that section)

Can anybody share how to do this with HTML & CSS?

I'm just a beginner, but I was thinking of maybe using two separate divs? With the 1st div having a background colour (position: relative;) and the 2nd div (position: absolute;) with the png being overlayed at the bottom of the 1st div? But I couldn't get that to work - so seeking any help here please!

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.color{
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: aqua;
    position: relative;
}

img{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
    <div class="color"></div>
    <img src="https://oneolympus.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/hosting-company-01.png" alt="waves">
```

Comment: Please provide at least some of your code so we can help. We are not here to write the code for you.

Comment: Hey Minal, sorry about that - I've updated the post to show the solution that I thought would work.

Comment: _“Can anybody share how to do this with HTML & CSS?”_ - well oneolympus.com already “shared” their implementation with you, so you can go use your browser dev tools, and find out …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you know that you can have a series of background images?

As the wavy png is really part of the background rather than part of the content of the page you could do something like this:

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(https://oneolympus.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/hosting-company-01.png), linear-gradient(to right, blue, cyan);
  background-size: 100% 30%, 100% 100%;
  background-position: 0 bottom, 0 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Note: the first image in the background image takes precedence, so the order they are declared in matters.

Answer (score 0):

https://i.ibb.co/3dqCnkx/rsz-aachk3.png

[OR]

https://i.ibb.co/t8pXkqP/aachk2.png

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!--GOOGLE FONTS-->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Archivo&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <style>
    body{
    margin:0;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    font-family: 'Archivo', sans-serif;
    }
    a{
    text-decoration:none;
    }
    #btn1,.btn1{
    padding:8px 20px;
    border-radius:20px;
    color:#4fc7f3;
    box-shadow:0px 6px 16px -6px rgba(1,1,1,0.5);
    outline:none;
    border:0;
    background:#fff;
    margin:5px 0;
    }
    .title{
    font-size:3em;
    }
    .sub-title{
    font-size:1em;
    }
    .title,.sub-title{
    color:#fff;
    display:block;
    }

    /*TOPNAV*/
    header{
    width:100%;
    background:transparent;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    z-index:1;
    }

    .topnav {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color:transparent;
    margin:30px;
    }

    .topnav a {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-size:bold;
    transition:0.5s;
    }

    .topnav .icon {
    display: none;
    }

    .topnav .logo{
    float:left;
    }

    .topnav .logo img{
    height:60px;
    }

    .dropdown {
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
    }

    .dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 17px;    
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    font-size:bold;
    transition:0.5s;ss
    }

    .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    }

    .topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    color:#000;
    }

    .dropdown-content a:hover {
    color:#000;
    }

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
    }
    .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
    .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    }
    .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    }
    .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
    .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
    .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    }
    }

    /*CONTAINER*/
    .container{
    width:100%;
    height:90vh;
    background-image:url("https://i.ibb.co/t8pXkqP/aachk2.png");
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    }

    .container section{
    text-align:center;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <!--HEADER-->
    <header>
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a href="#" class="logo"><img src="" alt="LOGO."></a>
    <a href="#" id="btn1">Get in Touch</a>
    <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
    <a href="#">PRICING</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">SERVICES 
    <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    </div>
    </div> 
    <a href="#about">ABOUT</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
    </div>
    </header>

    <!--CONTAINER-->
    <div class="container">
    <section>
    <span class="sub-title">Automate your digital marketing</span>
    <span class="title">At a fixed price</span>
    </section>
    </div>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
    }
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```